# How to install Uglify on Debian Sid

Tags: debian, compression, javascript

I have a question about how to install Uglify or Uglify2 on Debian. I'm also
wondering whether I have to install Node.js as well.

My main goal of asking this question is to minify all my CSS and .js files and gzip/compress them so that the page load on my website gets faster for visitors.

I was looking over the net for a step by step tutorial on how to do that, but got nothing handy so far.

Does any one know how to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You install `uglify-js` with `npm` which comes from Node.js

Install the `npm` package (which depends on `nodejs`)

```
apt-get install npm
```

Install uglifyjs

```
npm install --global uglifyjs
```

Now you have `uglify-js`

```
$ uglifyjs --version
uglify-js 2.4.13
```

Alternatively you can download the Node.js [linux binaries](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v4.x/) from the [download page](http://nodejs.org/download/).

```
wget https://nodejs.org/dist/v4.4.5/node-v4.4.5-linux-x64.tar.gz
```

Then extract Node to somewhere of your choosing

```
tar -C /opt -xvzf node-v4.4.5-linux-x64.tar.gz
export PATH="$PATH:/opt/node-v4.4.5-linux-x86/bin"
```

Or install Node system-wide

```
tar -C /usr/local --strip-components 1 -xvzf node-v4.4.5-linux-x64.tar.gz
```

Answer (score 1):

clone the repository

```
mkdir -p /where/you/wanna/put/it
cd /where/you/wanna/put/it
git clone git://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS.git
```

make the module available to Node

```
mkdir -p ~/.node_libraries/
cd ~/.node_libraries/
ln -s /where/you/wanna/put/it/UglifyJS/uglify-js.js
```

and if you want the CLI script too:

```
mkdir -p ~/bin
cd ~/bin
ln -s /where/you/wanna/put/it/UglifyJS/bin/uglifyjs
```

(then add `~/bin` to your `$PATH` if it's not there already)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the great explanation. I wish I could mark your answer,too. Thanks again.